# Hover a specific div - Change another div

Tags: html, css

I want to change background color of a div when hovering on another one. The first div is going to be black, but not change when hover over. When hovering over the second div, the background on that is going to turn black, and the first div is going to turn white. I have done this before, but it seems like it doesn't work anymore.

**CSS**

```
.svart {
    background-color: black;
}

.hvit {
    background-color: white;
}

.hvit:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="bestill_forside" class="svart">
    One
    </div>

    <div id="lear_forside" class="hvit">
    Two
</div>
```

**I have tried the following:**

```
.hvit:hover .svart {
        background-color: white;
}

.hvit:hover + .svart {
        background-color: white;
}

.hvit:hover > .svart {
        background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: You can't do this using CSS without changing your markup. CSS doesn't have any previous selectors. I'd suggest, use JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Answer (score 2):

`.svart` must be below `.hvit` in the document, you cannot select previous elements in CSS:

```
    <div id="lear_forside" class="hvit">
    Two
    </div>
    <div id="bestill_forside" class="svart">
    One
    </div>
```

What your CSS selectors were doing was:

```
.hvit:hover .svart {
        background-color: white; */This Selected .svart inside of .hvit*/
}

.hvit:hover + .svart {
        background-color: white; */This Selected .svart that was a immediate sibling of .hvit*/
}

.hvit:hover > .svart {
        background-color: white; */This Selected .svart that was a direct child of .hvit*/
}
```

Read more about CSS selectors:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors